# JUnit tests fail with Java error when using IntelliJ within maven module after adding Hibernate Metamodel classes

Tags: maven, jpa, intellij-idea, junit, criteria

On my project we've used Hibernate's (JPA) Metamodel Generator to make our Criteria queries type safe.  It all works great within our app, however, when we run the JUnit tests within that Maven module using our IDE they now fail with the following error:-

`Error:java: Annotation processor 'org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor' not found`

Which I guess is due to the following in our generated classes:-

`@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(MyEntity.class)`

When Maven runs the tests as part of our build process then they run with no problems at all.

I suspect I'm missing something within the set up of my IDE, which is IntelliJ IDEA 14.  Any ideas what this might be?  Or have I done something wrong within Maven? :-

```
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem after I upgraded to **IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2**.  For me the following action resolved the problem:

> Go to Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors.

On the left of this configuration panel I have an **`Annotation profile`** for every maven module in my project.  I did not set up these profiles myself: maybe they where inferred by the `IDE`. I don't know, but in some of these annotation profiles, the **enable annotation processing** `flag` was enabled.  Moreover, in some cases, the **JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor** was explicitly listed here as an annotation processor.  After **removing** the **annotation processor** from the profile and disabling the `checkbox`, the error disappeared and my test ran successfully.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @Jeroen Noels disables annotation processing in IDEA.

To keep it enabled I've added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

to the Maven dependencies, i.e. to the classpath. Note that the scope is `provided`!

Comment: Yep, +1 for the workaround.  The cause is this IDEA bug : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131241

Comment: I already have this dependency in my pom.xml, thus I finally applied @Jeroen method.